# How to create PHP login form redirecting back to the page preserving $_POST and $_GET

Tags: php, forms, post, authentication, get

For example, user work with a site, fill the form with some information and click a button or just click a link, but server finds that user in not logged in (any more, for some reasons). Server have to send a login form to user, user fill login form and click OK, after that user have to be send to request page, i.e. like he filled form or clicked an uri link (isn't it?). So, preserving $_GET looks easy --- use $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]

```
 echo '<form action = "'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'" method = "post">'.
      '<input type = "text" name = "login">'.
      '<input type = "password" name = "password">'.
      '<input type = "submit" value = "OK" name = "login_form">'.
      '</form>';
```

but how to preserver $_POST? Am I to iterate through all elements of this array to create hidden inputs in this form or there is an idea to do it more easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the $_POST data to the user's session:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['form_elements'] = $_POST;
```

Then restore the data from the session after the user logs in.

Comment: You could just do: session_start(); $_SESSION['form_elements'] = $_POST; and it would do the same thing.

Comment: Well, save POST to session sounds like a better idea since if user just press enter to the address in browser it will preserve POST too. So, I may check log in form and authorize (or not) and restore $_POST by $_POST = $_SESSION['form_elements'] like there was no login form entered.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do this:

1. As you suggested, put the fields into the login form as hidden form fields.
2. Serialize the $_POST array, store it in a a session or in a cookie (don't use a cookie if the data can be very large) and then on your destination page, check for the presence of the session data or cookie and unserialize it again if the data is there.

Comment: The first way looks easy since no need to convert data or check $_POST from different sources on destination page

Comment: Someone else answered with an example of using method #2 via sessions. Feel free to up-vote me though and give me some points ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to examine why you want to preserve GET or POST variables.
What you are really doing is attempting to preserve *state* across page requests, using variables that are meant for one-shot data input from the user.

I would recommend saving whatever state you need to save in a *session*, and associate that with a *cookie* that you can reference when the client requests a page. In fact, PHP has session functionality to do all this for you automatically - see http://us.php.net/sessions.

If you have a lot of state to carry around with each user, consider making the session a primary key in a session table in your database backend, that can foreign key to other data when you need it.

As a side note, **never trust** GET or POST data to be what you expect it to be, in the context of security. Both are easy to access and modify outside the control of you server scripts.

Comment: Yup, I see, but in any case $_GET and $_POST is user sent data and no matter if it is modified before login form or after. Appearance of this login form is an accident caused by server's session outdating or user's cookie cleaned during work.

Comment: Ah - I see. You want to recall the state - making it independent of the session. I did this once with an accounting portal. I had a table of sessions in a db, and I would make them stale after a time period (requiring a login), and then would actually remove them after a longer period. This might be overkill for what you are trying to accomplish, so YMMV :)

Comment: Hm, there is a lot of to think about really. Thanks.